# Como esconder algo com jquery e css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

preciso esconder algumas coisas usando o jquery junto com o css , tentei usar o hide() mas não funcionou...
alguma solução??

meu codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#ID_USER')hide();//não funcionou...

});
```

Comment: Falta um ponto: `$('#ID_USER').hide();`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se está resgatando o ID do elemento correto, se o elemento já existe na página e coloque um `.` **entre a seleção do elemento e a chamada do método `hide`**. A partir disso você pode esconder o elemento. As duas formas que considero mais simples:

Usando `hide`:

`$("#ID_USER").hide();`

Ou alterando o estilo do seu elemento:

`$("#ID_USER").css('display', 'none');`

O método `css` te permite alterar a estilização do elemento e é bastante flexível para outros tipos de uso também. [Recomendo ler mais sobre](https://api.jquery.com/css/).

Para exibir o elemento novamente, você pode usar `show()` ou alterar o estilo ainda usando o método `css`:

`$("#ID_USER").show();`

`$("#ID_USER").css('display', 'block');`

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.

Comment: obrigado amigo !! ajudou muito !!

Answer (score 0):

Talvez você tenha esquecido de um ponto, deve funcionar assim:

```
$('#ID_USER').hide();
```

Comment: mudei la mas não adiantou... Mas fiz como o parceiro aqui de baixo falou , usando .css().. mesmo assim obrigado!!